# How to modify lxml autolink to be more liberal?

Tags: python, regex, hyperlink, lxml

I am using the autolink function of the great lxml library as documented here: http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html.clean-module.html

My problem is that it only detects urls that start with **http://**.
I would like to use a broader url detection regex like this one:
http://daringfireball.net/2010/07/improved_regex_for_matching_urls

I tried to make that regex work with the lxml autolink function without success.
I always end up with a:

```
lxml\html\clean.py", line 571, in _link_text
host = match.group('host')
IndexError: no such group
```

Any python/regex gurus out there who know how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things to do in order to adapt the regexp to lxml's autolink. First wrap the entire url pattern match in a group `(?P<body> .. )` - this lets lxml know what goes inside the `href=""` attribute.

Next, wrap the host part in a `(?<host> .. )` group and pass `avoid_hosts=[]` parameter when you call the autolink function.  The reason for this is the regexp pattern you're using doesn't always find a host (sometimes the `host` part will be `None`) since it matches partial urls and ambiguous url-like patterns.

I've modified the regexp to include the above changes and given a snippet test case:

```
import re
import lxml.html
import lxml.html.clean

url_regexp = re.compile(r"""(?i)\b(?P<body>(?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|(?P<host>[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/))(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))""")

DOC = """<html><body>
    http://foo.com/blah_blah
    http://foo.com/blah_blah/.
    http://www.extinguishedscholar.com/wpglob/?p=364.
    http://✪df.ws/1234
    rdar://1234
    rdar:/1234
    message://%3c330e7f840905021726r6a4ba78dkf1fd71420c1bf6ff@mail.gmail.com%3e
    What about &lt;mailto:gruber@daringfireball.net?subject=TEST&gt; (including brokets).
    bit.ly/foo
</body></html>"""

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(DOC)
body = tree.find('body')
lxml.html.clean.autolink(body, [url_regexp], avoid_hosts=[])
print lxml.html.tostring(tree)
```

Output:

```
<html><body>
    <a href="http://foo.com/blah_blah">http://foo.com/blah_blah</a>
    <a href="http://foo.com/blah_blah/">http://foo.com/blah_blah/</a>.
    <a href="http://www.extinguishedscholar.com/wpglob/?p=364">http://www.extinguishedscholar.com/wpglob/?p=364</a>.
    <a href="http://%C3%A2%C2%9C%C2%AAdf.ws/1234">http://&#226;&#156;&#170;df.ws/1234</a>
    <a href="rdar://1234">rdar://1234</a>
    <a href="rdar:/1234">rdar:/1234</a>
    <a href="message://%3c330e7f840905021726r6a4ba78dkf1fd71420c1bf6ff@mail.gmail.com%3e">message://%3c330e7f840905021726r6a4ba78dkf1fd71420c1bf6ff@mail.gmail.com%3e</a>
    What about &lt;<a href="mailto:gruber@daringfireball.net?subject=TEST">mailto:gruber@daringfireball.net?subject=TEST</a>&gt;
    (including brackets).
    <a href="bit.ly/foo">bit.ly/foo</a>
</body></html>
```

Comment: thats one hell of a regex... but it works like charm. One problem remains: **<a href="bit.ly/foo">bit.ly/foo</a>** will link to a subfolder and not to the domain... how would you fix that?

Comment: The regexp you provided will match url-link text but the clean.autolink function is a black box: it won't let you pass a callback to modify the links before it encodes them. I'd recommend copying the clean.autolink and clean._link_text functions, strip out what you don't use, and customize the behavior a bit.. specifically as you loop over the matched urls, find those without a `Host` part and prepend the `http://` scheme to the url (and any other rules you wish to apply).

Comment: thanks... I have it working now... solved it by simple postprocessing. (for link in body.xpath('//a'): ....)

Answer (score 0):

You don't really give enough information to be sure, but I bet that you're having escaping issues with the backslashes in Gruber's regex. Try using a raw string, which allows backslashes without escaping, and triple-quotes, which allow you to use quotes in the string without having to escape those either.  E.g.

```
re.compile(r"""(?i)\b((?:[a-z][\w-]+:(?:/{1,3}|[a-z0-9%])|www\d{0,3}[.]|[a-z0-9.\-]+[.][a-z]{2,4}/)(?:[^\s()<>]+|\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\))+(?:\(([^\s()<>]+|(\([^\s()<>]+\)))*\)|[^\s`!()\[\]{};:'".,<>?«»“”‘’]))""")
```

Comment: thats exactly what tried to pass to the autolink function ;.) but it fails with:
    lxml\html\clean.py", line 571, in _link_text
    host = match.group('host')
    IndexError: no such group

Comment: Ahhh, looking more at lxml, they are expecting it to yield named match groups, which Gruber's regex, being designed to match the whole URL, does not have. There will need to be rather more extensive surgery on the regex to achieve that; maybe I can look at it more tonight, assuming someone else doesn't post a solution.